# How to create dynamic type DbSet in Entity Framework .Net Core application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

In application database from time to time new tables will be created. I need to access this tables without code changes and show tables content in web application.
Probably, I could make reflection query to get new tables and their column names.

After that I can add dynamic DbSet to EntityFramework context:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity("EntityName", config =>
        {
            config.Property("Id").HasColumnType("int");
            config.Property("Name").HasMaxLength(255);
            config.HasKey("Id");

        });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Unfortunately, when I run migration (dotnet ef migrations add MigrationName)
Entity Framework shows migration error:

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
>      at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImplCommon(String name, Int32 genericParameterCount, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
>      at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
>      at System.Type.GetMethod(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
>      at DynamicEF.AppContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in C:\Users\aleks\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DynamicEF\DynamicEF\AppContext.cs:line 19
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
>      at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
>      at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalAccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   Ambiguous match found.

I'm confused about "Ambiguous match found".

Where is my mistake? How I should change my code to fix migration process?

Comment: You havent shown enough code there to explain why you are getting that exception.. I’ve never heard of EF being used generically/dynamically like this before, so it would be useful to have more context